# Is $r(^∗)=r^∗$ valid regular expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

Which of the following regular expression identities is/are TRUE?

1. $r(^∗)=r^∗$
2. $(r^∗s^∗)=(r+s)^∗$
3. $(r+s)^∗=r^∗+s^∗$
4. $ r^∗s^∗=r^∗+s^∗$

---

My attempt :

1. I can't say anything, but it should be invalid.
2. $LHS\subset RHS$
3. $RHS\subset LHS$
4. $RHS\subset LHS$

---

My question is :

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

As [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) given on wiki : Regular expressions consist of constants and operator symbols that denote sets of strings and operations over these sets, respectively.

Comment: I don’t consider $r(^*)$ a valid regular expression.

Comment: So, none option is correct, rt?

Comment: Yes, at least by the definition of *regular expression* with which I’m familiar.

Comment: Including your definition of regular expression, if nonstandard, might be helpful